# Find average clients per hour for a Markov process

Tags: markov-process

I'm stuck in a problem on Markov jump process:

A gas station receives cars at a rate of 20 vehicles per hour, the station has only one gas pump. If the pump is empty, it receives one client, if a new client comes and find that the pump is occupied by a client he waits. Every client takes around 6 minutes to fill his vehicle (1/10th of an hour). If two clients are at the pump, one filling and the other one waiting, new clients would leave the station directly.

**Solution**:

Modeling this problem we have the states are the number of clients at the pump at any instant $t$, so we would increment by one with a rate of 20, and decrement by one (leave the station) by a rate of 10 (because it takes in average 1/10th of hour to fill the vehicle).

So the Jump rate matrix for the chain with the following states $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-20 & \phantom{-}20 & \phantom{-1}0 \\\phantom{-}10 & -30 & \phantom{-}20 \\ \phantom{-1}0 &\phantom{-}10 &-10  \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for the stationary distribution we find:

$$(u_1,u_2,u_3) = (1/7,2/7,4/7) $$

Now I'm asked to find the average number of clients served by the gas station every hour. The answer should be 50/7, but I can't find how to get this.